# C++ Linux Google Protocol Buffers - cannot run compiled proto cpp files from tutorial

Tags: c++, g++, protocol-buffers

I'm following the [cpp tutorial on google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial)

I installed Google Protocol Buffers on Ubuntu and compiled the .proto file so I got the pb.h and pb.cc generated files.

[image]

I made ReadAddressBook.cpp very minimal. It just creates the proto object and verifies if the version matches.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "address_book.pb.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

 GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

 tutorial::AddressBook address_book;

return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with

```
g++ -c ReadAddressBook.cpp
```

(also with g++ -c ReadAddressBook.cpp -lprotobuf -lpthread but it gave the same results)

However when running:

```
g++ -o ReadAddressBook ReadAddressBook.o
```

[image]

It gave me the references to the google protobuf src was unavailable. Why would this be?

Comment: You should add `address_book.pb.cc` for compilation and linking. try this `g++  ReadAddressBook.cpp  address_book.pb.cc  -lprotobuf -lpthread `.

Comment: @nomem Then when I compile after do I put g++ -c ReadAddressBook.cpp or g++ -c ReadAddressBook.cpp address_book.pb.cc? What would be the next steps?

Comment: the command I gave would directly make the executable. If you want to compile then link then try this: `g++ -c ReadAddressBook.cpp address_book.pb.cc` and `g++ -o ReadAddressBook ReadAddressBook.o address_book.pb.o -lprotobuf -lpthread`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-lprotobuf` to the *link* phase, but it looks like you tried to use it in the compile phase. That is, you want to do:

```
g++ -c ReadAddressBook.cpp
g++ -o ReadAddressBook ReadAddressBook.o -lprotobuf -lpthread
```